# Solver não calcula solução para modelo

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu implementei uma rotina que faz cálculo da porcentagem apropriada de ingredientes que é necessário para formular uma ração.

Para fazer esse cálculo estou usando o `Solver Foundation` da **MS**.

A princípio eu seto as decisões com os valores máximos e mínimos de cada ingrediente (eu quero a porcentagem de cada ingrediente que deve ser inserida na ração, a soma de cada porcentagem deve ser 100). Depois, eu faço uma outra restrição que é a dos nutrientes (cada ingrediente contribui com mais ou menos de um nutriente de acordo com a porcentagem do ingrediente que é inserido). No final minha solução deve apresentar a fórmula mais barata, visto que os ingredientes tem um preço.

Segue meu código:

```
     private Solution FormularRacao()
     {
        var ingredientesRacao = _formulacaoRacao.CarregarIngredientesNutrientesFormulacao(true);
        var nutrientes = _formulacaoRacao.CarregarIngredientesNutrientesFormulacao(false);
        var formulacao = _formulacaoRacao.CarregarFormulacao();

        SolverContext context = SolverContext.GetContext();
        context.ClearModel();

        Model model = context.CreateModel();

        var objetivo = new SumTermBuilder(ingredientesRacao.Count);
        var totalIngrediente = new SumTermBuilder(ingredientesRacao.Count);

        List<SumTermBuilder> listaTotalNutriente = new List<SumTermBuilder>();

        //Set decisions
        foreach (var item in ingredientesRacao)
        {
            item.Nome = TratarNome(item.Nome);

            Decision d = new Decision(Domain.RealRange(Convert.ToDouble(item.Minimo), Convert.ToDouble(item.Maximo)), "d_" + item.Nome);

            model.AddDecision(d);

            objetivo.Add(Model.Product(d, Convert.ToDouble(item.Custo)));
            totalIngrediente.Add(d);
            listaTotalNutriente.Add(new SumTermBuilder(nutrientes.Count));
        }

        var SomaIngrediente = totalIngrediente.ToTerm();

        //total of values of decisions must be equal 100
        model.AddConstraint("c_totalIngrediente", SomaIngrediente == 100);

        //totalIngrediente;
        model.AddGoal("racao", GoalKind.Minimize, objetivo.ToTerm());

        int indexIngrediente = 0;
        int indexNutriente = 0;

        //each ingredient contributes with nutrients
        //each nutrient has a min and max set            
        foreach (var ingredienteRacao in ingredientesRacao)
        {
            Ingrediente ingrediente = _formulacaoRacao.CarregarIngrediente(ingredienteRacao.Id);
            indexNutriente = 0;
            ingredienteRacao.Nome = TratarNome(ingredienteRacao.Nome);
            Decision d = model.Decisions.First(x => x.Name == "d_" + ingredienteRacao.Nome);

            foreach (var nutriente in nutrientes)
            {
                var valor = new object();

                if (nutriente.AminoacidoDigestivo.Equals("S"))
                {
                    var aminoacidoDigestivo = _formulacaoRacao.CarregarAminoacidoDigestivo(ingredienteRacao.Id);
                    valor = aminoacidoDigestivo.GetType().GetProperty(nutriente.Nome).GetValue(aminoacidoDigestivo, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    nutriente.Nome = TratarNomeNutriente(nutriente.Nome);
                    valor = ingrediente.GetType().GetProperty(nutriente.Nome).GetValue(ingrediente, null);
                }

                var proporcaoNutriente = Convert.ToDouble(valor.ToString()) * d;

                listaTotalNutriente[indexNutriente].Add(proporcaoNutriente / 100);

                if (indexIngrediente == ingredientesRacao.Count - 1) //last iteration
                {
                    var totalNutriente = listaTotalNutriente[indexNutriente].ToTerm();
                    if (nutriente.Minimo == nutriente.Maximo)
                       model.AddConstraint("c_" + nutriente.Nome, totalNutriente == Convert.ToDouble(nutriente.Maximo));                        
                    else
                        model.AddConstraint("c" + nutriente.Nome, Convert.ToDouble(nutriente.Minimo) <= totalNutriente <= Convert.ToDouble(nutriente.Maximo));                        
                }

                indexNutriente++;
            }
            indexIngrediente++;
        }           

        //salva o modelo
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Caminho\arquivo.oml");
        context.SaveModel(FileFormat.OML, tw);
        tw.Close();

        //Imprime o modelo
        TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("Caminho\arquivo.txt");
        foreach (var item in model.Constraints.ToList())
        {
            txt.WriteLine(item.Name + ":  " + item.Expression);
            txt.WriteLine();
        }
        txt.Close(); 

        Solution solution = context.Solve();

        return solution;
    }
```

O modelo não é resolvido, pois os ingredientes estão setados com o valor mínimo definido na declaração da `decision`.

Minha pergunta é: **porque os valores das `decisions` são definidos com o valor mínimo declarado ao invés de serem calculados pelo `solver`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A implementação estava correta e o código também roda ok. O problema foi a criação do modelo mesmo, pois o mesmo não conseguia encontrar uma solução que atendesse a todos as restrições. O que me ajudou (e muito) foi criar um arquivo txt e inserir nele todas as restrições e também um arquivo oml e depois importá-lo no excel para testar o modelo. Atualizei o meu código na pergunta para mostrar a criação dos arquivos.